# How random forest apply on clustering technique to check the accuracy of the method

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I have the following codes and want to apply random forest classifier by one of a simple function. Actually, x is my clustering technique and y is the response in the training set. Then to find coefficient by `glm` method to select only the genes that have a contribution. `reduced_data` is the combination of my method that for features selection i:e. "Selection" and "oderedfeatures". Here they give an error which I closed in steric sign. I have total $72$ samples in the data.  How have gene number 4847 differed length? Because if you observe the following samples all have the same in size.

anyone help/suggest me. Thanks in advance for your consideration.

```
cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y)

fit <- glmnet(x=x,y=y,alpha=1, family = "binomial")

coefs <- coef(fit,s=cv.fit$lambda.min)

reduced_data <- leukaemia[c(selects,lassoselects),]

reduced_data <- t(reduced_data)

myrf<- randomForest(y~.,data=reduced_data)#,ntree=100,mtry=5,importance=TRUE,proximity=TRUE)
```

*> **Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ ., data = list(`gene 4847` = c(0.102796,  :    variable lengths differ (found for 'gene 4847')***

> reduced_data

```
       gene 4847  gene 15 gene 888 gene 1058 gene 4787
```

sample 1   0.102796 0.495544 0.928571  0.513619  0.540698

sample 2   0.178811 0.424242 1.000000  0.322957  0.127907

sample 3   0.090981 0.003565 0.741758  0.315175  0.825581

sample 4   0.000000 0.103387 0.670330  0.926070  0.773256

sample 5   0.139228 0.586453 0.879121  0.758755  0.406977

sample 6   0.122686 0.028520 0.543956  0.688716  0.616279

sample 7   0.113234 0.171123 0.950549  0.782101  0.802326

sample 8   0.209334 0.520499 0.851648  0.797665  0.773256

sample 9   0.119141 0.525847 0.675824  0.809339  0.930233

sample 10  0.205199 0.475936 0.846154  0.723735  0.906977

.........................................................
.           .         .     .            .        .
.           .         .     .            .        .
.           .         .     .            .        .

sample 69  1.000000 0.814558 0.333333  0.314286  0.309735

sample 70  1.000000 0.814558 0.333333  0.314286  0.309735

sample 71  1.000000 0.814558 0.333333  0.314286  0.309735

sample 72  1.000000 0.814558 0.333333  0.314286  0.309735